# Not reading complete Serial Port data in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm using .Net framework 4 and create a serial port GUI application in C#. In some cases, the SerialPort object (port) doesn't receive all the data (I compare it with a Mixed Signal Oscilloscope)

For example, if the connected device sends:

0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09

I can receive:

0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 **0x04 0x08** 0x09

I tried different codes having the same issue:

- Use the data received event to fill a buffer:

  ```
      private void dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
          while (port.BytesToRead > 0){
              byte[] newBytes = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
              int LengthRead = port.Read(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
              Array.Resize(ref newBytes, LengthRead);
              System.Buffer.BlockCopy(newBytes, 0, buffer, positionInBuffer, newBytes.Length);
              positionInBuffer += newBytes.Length;
          }
      }
  ```
- Looping for an expected number of bytes, in this case causing the TimeoutException:

  ```
          while (port.BytesToRead < expectedSize)
      {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
          waitingLoop++;
          if (waitingLoop > TimeOut)             // wait for a 1s timeout
              throw new TimeoutException();
      }

      newBytes = new byte[expectedSize];
      LengthRead = port.Read(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
      if (LengthRead != newBytes.Length)
          throw new TimeoutException(); // or any exception, doesn't matter...
  ```

I tried to change the ReadBufferSize size, the timeout info,... but nothing works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There are subtle mistakes in this code.  The first snippet's Array.Resize() does nothing, maybe *buffer* needs to be resized instead?  The second snippet bombs on a TimeoutException when *more* bytes were received than *expectedSize*.  Which is certainly possible and not a timeout problem.

But I think the real problem is what you do with the array outside of this code.  In general, calling SerialPort.Read() only gets you a couple of bytes.  Serial ports are slow.  You need some kind of protocol to know when a 'full' response is received.  A very common (non-binary) one is simply terminating the response with a line-feed.  Then you'd just use ReadLine() in the DataReceived event handler.  It isn't obvious what the proper approach would be in your case.

Also implement the ErrorReceived event.  It will tell you when something bad happened, like SerialError.Overrun or RXOver, errors that also make bytes disappear.

Comment: You were right, something bad happened as I got SerialError.Overrun.
If I correctly understand, this error is an Hardware overrun, right?
Is handshaking proposed by Joe could help me solve this kind of issue?
I'm using FTDI chip to convert RS232 (without the HW flow control lines) to USB but I am not sure I can correctly use the SW flow control in that case.

Comment: No, that's a soft overrun, the buffer overflowed.  Remarkable on modern machines, unless you are debugging.  Increase ReadBufferSize, set HandShake to RequestToSend.  The latter requires the device to implement handshaking as well, most do.

Comment: ReadBufferSize is currently set to 4096 and when my timeout exception come up the port BytesToRead is currently << ~800. I also tried to set HandShake to RequestToSend but it doesn't communicate at all. I guess this is because the computer ask for data but I don't have the hardware flow control lines connected, right?

Comment: Erm, why do you get a TimeoutException with 800 bytes in the buffer?  That should never happen.  Don't mess with ReceivedBytesThreshold.  Yes, hardware handshake cannot work if the RTS and DTR lines aren't wired.

Comment: I am using the following protocol: <ID><SIZE><DATA....><CHECKSUM>. So, after reading the SIZE data, I know the number of data I should expect. It's at maximum ~800 bytes so I set the buffer size to 4096 to be safe. In my 2nd example I used the SerialPort buffer to be 'minimalist' in my code, and I wait to receive all the trame in this buffer before reading it. I tried to double buffer it (with datareceived) but I got the same result.

Comment: By the way, my protocol is something like: (computer)'please send the next trame' ... (connected device)'Ack' ... (connected device) <ID> <SIZE> <DATA....> <CHECKSUM>. So I always have a hand on the maximum number of bytes and know that the SerialPort buffer size is safe. That's why I thought about hardware overrun...

Comment: None of this is visible in your snippet, you are not making it easy to help you.  A timeout should always be at least 10 times larger than the expected time, 1 msec per byte at 9600 baud.  I was mistaken in an earlier comment, SerialError.Overrun is indeed a hardware overrun.  Handshaking cannot solve this, you'll have to lower the Baudrate.

Comment: Sorry for the visibility, I tried to simplify the code in oder to explain it better but it seems it did the opposite. As I can't lower the Baudrate (as time to dowload the data is already huge... 30Mb/h), I will have to implement the section to ask again for the incorrect trame when the overrun occurs. Thanks for your support

Comment: 30 megaBytes?  That is as fast as a serial port could ever run, you'll need 115 kilobaud to keep up with that.  Throw away the serial port gadget you use on your PC now, you need a better one with a driver than can keep up.  This really ought to be done with Ethernet.

Comment: :) I would really love to change serial port gadget but I can't because it would need a complete rework of the system itself which will cost too much. All the architecture has to be rebuild if I do so...

Comment: You are only at stage 1 of the 5 stages of grief.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure software (XON/XOF) or hardware (e.g. RTS/CTS) handshaking on the serial port, to match the configuration of the device that's transmitting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

Actually I have some kind of protocol in the serial data. It's something like:

```
<ID><SIZE><DATA....><CHECKSUM>
```

I usually correctly get the ID, the SIZE and then I listen for the expected 'size' data bytes (size is less than 1000 and the serial port running at 115200, so it should be a short time).
But when I wait for them, for example with the 2nd code (waiting loop), they never come up on my C# code even if they are really passing thought the serial line (checked with the scope). Still running the 2nd code, I got the 1st TimeOutException (on the waiting loop) which means I don't receive all the data within the 1s (also tried to increase to 5s). So the error is catch before going to the SerialPort.Read() function.

Anyway, I will check for the ErrorReceived event to check if I catch something...

Regarding the Array.Resize() I wrote this in case the returned data of SerialPort.Read() has less bytes than the expected ones. Buffer is pre-sized at the max size of my SerialPort buffer (4096).
Regarding my 2nd mistake in the code you are complitly right. I should better use a more appropriate exception :)